# ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label default not found in scene default

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, click

I have asked this question on the http://www.actionscript.org/ forums, I have yet to get a reply, so I will try here as well, I will copy the post from those forums, but please do tell me if I am missing any details out, posting it on the wrong forum on this website, or whether I should actually post it to another website.

The post is as follows:

I am fairly new to using action script 3.0, I am following a set of video tutorials for such.

I am using Adobe Flash Professional CC 2014, along with some extra elements, to create the main menu for a game using UDK(Unreal Development Kit), that I have in mind, to confirm, this is a test game, not intended for release, it will be free to try when I get various features implemented, a practice project.

So, I am using Scaleform and CLIK. When I run what I have so far, using the Scaleform launcher, everything works as intended, no errors are logged in the console. However, when I use the debugger and click on the 'Options' button on my main menu (it is the only button in frames 1-10, at the moment, under the 'mainMenuScreen' label that I have declared), I get the following error:

ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label default not found in scene default.
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at scaleform.clik.controls::Slider/draw()[C:\UDK\UDK-2014-08\Development\Flash\AS3\CLIK\scaleform\clik\contr ols\Slider.as:273]
at scaleform.clik.controls::Slider/set value()[C:\UDK\UDK-2014-08\Development\Flash\AS3\CLIK\scaleform\clik\contr ols\Slider.as:156]
at MainMenu_fla::MainTimeline/frame10()[MainMenu_fla.MainTimeline::frame10:11]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at MainMenu_fla::MainTimeline/OpenGameplayOptionsScreen()[MainMenu_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:17]

I am not using a label known as 'default', nor do I have a scene called 'default' and also, as can be seen from the code for the button, I am not trying to go to (gotoAndPlay), 'default', I am trying to go to a label I have defined, known as 'gameplayOptionsScreen', the code is as follows:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/*Function
@Name:  OpenGamePlayOptionsScreen
@Params: None
@Description: This function will make the scene go to the "gameplayOptionsScreen"
label, so that the components that will be on the screen will now be those under the 
label of "gameplayOptionsScreen".
*/

function OpenGameplayOptionsScreen(evt : MouseEvent)
{
gotoAndPlay("gameplayOptionsScreen");
}

// Add an event listener to this button, so it can tell if it has been clicked on, // in this case:
optionsBtn.addEventListener("click", OpenGameplayOptionsScreen);
(The line above this one, is where the debugger highlights one of the places the error occurs)


stop(); // Stop the flash movie here
```

From what problems that the debugger has informed me of, it also seems to have a problem with the slider that appears in frame 10, the frame that the label, 'gameplayOptionsScreen', is assigned too.

But I am wondering why the error occurs, in regards to a call to 'gotoAndPlay("gameplayOptionsScreen");', as that is where I believe the error becomes existent from.

Please do tell me if you require more information to help me solve this problem that I am having, or do tell me if I have posted this in the wrong forum on this website, or if I have in fact posted this to the wrong website altogether and therefore, should be posting to Epic Games' forums instead.

Edit: I have redone the button, so that, it is now known as TestGameButton and DefaultButton is in my library too, as it was in the click components library, this component has been left unchanged this time. Using my new button still produces the same errors and even using the default button does as well. But removing the slider that the debugger also complains about that is displayed in frame 10, removes all the errors, so it seems to be a problem with the slider, I am not sure what though, I have tried putting in a new instance and naming it, but I get similar errors .

Comment: There is now an edit in the post, describing what I have recently tried, please have a look

Comment: Please tell me if you need anything else, or why you rated this question down, I would like to know

Comment: I think your misreading the error message, its not talking about the Frame of a label called default, its refering to the default frame for your  labels

Comment: Thank you for the comment @CyanAngel, but I have my labels on different frames, so I do not understand why this would be the case, could you please explain how this could be so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind then, I don't mind if this question does not get any answers, I am moving onto UE4, which has much better systems in place for menus, for example, thanks for trying to help @CyanAngel though.